# How to fix the error: at-rule or selector expectedscss(css-ruleorselectorexpected) in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, tailwind-css, postcss

I am trying to use TailwindCSS combined with SCSS but VSCode always give me an error message when i openning this file, how can i fix it?

[image for this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnEUo.png)

my config in postcss file:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};
```

my config in VSCode settings.json:

```
{
    ...
    "css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore",
    "css.lint.emptyRules": "ignore",
    "scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore",
    "scss.lint.emptyRules": "ignore"
}
```

I found the cause of the error is `#{!important}` in .scss file

Comment: fixed this problem by `"scss.validate": false` in settings.json of .vscode

Comment: You did not fix it. You just muted a linter. Faced the same and looking for solution

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this to user settings.json

```json
"files.associations": {
  "*.scss": "tailwindcss",
  "*.css": "tailwindcss"
},
```

Comment: Did that, still facing the same issue

Comment: And again, this rule doesn't work correctly for tw in scss files. Therefore, you just need to add each rule as pure scss

```h2 { font-size: 24px !important;}
```

Comment: i want to use @ apply though.